# Prime Factorization Program PHP

Tags: php, arrays, factorization

So I am currently trying to code a program that will find the prime factorization of any number.  I have been successful in doing so, I am just getting caught up on having it be represented properly.  For instance, the prime factorization of 82944 is (2^10)*(3^4).

My program successfully finds the prime factorization...just in a messy way.  I am close to representing it properly with the following:

```
$unique_factors = array_unique($f);
foreach($unique_factors as $factors){
    foreach(array_count_values($f) as $count){
        echo $factors . "<sup>" . $count . "</sup>";
    }
}
```

However, this outputs (2^10)(2^4)(3^10)(3^4)

(The array $f is the array containing 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have `$f` store the factors as keys with their counts as values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the outer loop - `array_count_values` returns (from the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)) "an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values."

So you just need to do this:

```
foreach(array_count_values($f) as $key=>$count){
    echo "$key<sup>$count</sup>";
}
```